# Is this sufficient to verify a website's domain?

Tags: web-browser, websites, browser-extensions, dns-domain

I'm building a browser extension that will run some javascript, which contains some sensitive information (essentially injecting authentication info). Therefore I want to make sure it only executes it when the browser is on my trusted domain (let's say www.trusted.com). My current check is something like this:

```
if (url.includes('https://www.trusted.com/')  || url.includes('https://trusted.com/')) {
    // do stuff
}
```

Where url is definitely the correct current URL, read straight from the browser. Is this a sufficient check? Why or why not? (If not, then how might I do it properly?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is this a sufficient check?

No, your check is flawed.

An attacker can bypass the validation via e.g.:

```
https://attacker.example/?https://www.trusted.com/
```

This URL resolves to the origin `attacker.example`, but satisfies `url.includes('https://www.trusted.com/')`.

> If not, then how might I do it properly?

E.g. use [`URL.origin`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/origin). If `url` is the URL string, you can do:

```
(new URL(url)).origin === "https://www.trusted.com"
```

In practice, this is also safe, but less expressive and easier to get wrong:

```
url.startsWith('https://www.trusted.com/')
```

Comment: There was a serious vulnerability in a Wordpress plugin some years ago, exactly because of this flawed check. Can't remember the name of the plugin, though.

Comment: Would it be sufficient to match only if it's at the beginning of the string? I.e. `url.startsWith('https://www.trusted.com/')`

Comment: @personjerry Yes, in practice that's safe. Personally, I find it cleaner think of URLs as objects with origin properties than strings of which you compare substrings.